# How to convert cURL -X -u, -H, -d to http post in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, curl

I am facing problem while converting cURL to flutter http post.

**Below is the cURL code available**

```
curl  -X POST url
-u <YOUR_KEY_ID>:<YOUR_SECRET>
-H 'content-type:application/json'
-d '{    "amount": 50000,    "currency": "INR",    "receipt": "rcptid_11"}'
```

**Below is the code that I have rewritten in flutter with the help of [flutter documentaion](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/send-data).**

```
  Future<Album> createAlbum() async{
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('url'),
      headers: {
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: '<$_key>:<$_secretKey>',
        HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        "amount": (amount*100).toString(),
        "currency": "INR",
        "receipt": date,
      }),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      print('Success');
      return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to create album.');
    }
  }
```

All the parameters are defined in the class and used in createAlbum method. http post fails to send data.

Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful to attach an error you receive. Till then I suppose that you pass wrong types to body parameters. "amount" is `String` in you code, but curl passes `int`. Try to remove `.toString()`.And also check that date is a string.

Comment: Yes, I have removed it and passed datatype as int by using jsonEncode(<String>, <dynamic>). There was issue in header(base64) as well as body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to base64 encode the basic auth and put the string `Basic`  before the user:password:

```
String basicAuth =
      'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$_key:$_secretKey'));
```

Then use this for the auth header:

```
// ... 
HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: basicAuth,
```